# Inserting variable along with data from select

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, jet

I have a query that currently inserts data from one table into another table,

```
moveQuery = "INSERT INTO results(ClassCode, AttemptDate, StudentID, Mark) 
SELECT F1,F2,F3,F4 FROM " & randtablename & " where F1 = '" & classcode & "'"
```

I'd like to insert an extra column from a variable while doing so.

How can I do this in Microsoft Access VBA?

Comment: What extra column you want to add? Please be clearer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO results(ClassCode, AttemptDate, StudentID, Mark, Other_column) 
SELECT F1,F2,F3,F4, 'extraVariable'
FROM ...
```